# Problem- consistent dpkg error processing package cannot configure

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

newer Ubuntu user here.Having issues with installs and updates. While attempting an install I received errors regarding some packages. Have attempted numerous generic solutions
(note I have already attempted   `apt-get clean, update, upgrade, install -f dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from previous questions and receive the same error.)
Sorry for my english and linux knowledge.Thanks

````
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up er
ror from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message i
ndicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        dpkg: dependency problem
s prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 5.4.0.81.85); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-generic; however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were 
encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

Comment: Are these messages during an install?

Comment: You may have to do `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` a few times until it works itself out.

Comment: Also, you should run `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic`

Comment: Please provide the error from the reinstallation command. Thanks.

Comment: I got the same error yesterday : "package is in a very bad inconsistent state" ..."No apport report written because ......"   → Fixed with `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: mchid your suggestion worked and I was able to reinstall the packages. Problem seems corrected now. Thanks!